# i write x++; it produce correct result.but when i write x=x+1 (or) x+=1 it produce wrong result..why it is happening?

Tags: javascript

//enter the value of x

var x=prompt("Enter the value of x:");

//x=x+1
x=x+1;

alert(x);

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVtmT.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R11en.png)

Comment: because x is a string

Comment: i write x++ it produe correct result.but write x=x+1 only it produce wrong result....

Comment: the increment operator (++) automatically converts the value to a number. I didn't find any detail about it on MDN, but you can see it in ECMAScript specifications: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-postfix-increment-operator

Comment: this line of pseudo code `2. Let oldValue be ? ToNumeric(? GetValue(lhs)).`, I'm pretty sure `ToNumeric` casts the string value to a number.

Comment: var x=prompt('Enter the number');
 var num1 = parseInt(x);
  num1+=5;
  alert(num1);